# Sorting text files based on elements from another file in python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a code in python that sort the lines in one text file based on the order of elements in another file.  For example I have "U4" as the first element so I'll search for U4 in the other file and put the line that contain this key word as first line (sorting).  The following code worked perfectly except for elements such as U1 , because when I tried to search for that it gave me the results for U1 , U11 , U111 , U12 , what should I do to fix it

code :

```
 def main(argv):


  inputs = []

  #Get python script arguments: Input/Output files

   inputfilea = argv[0]
   inputfileb = argv[1]
   outputfile = argv[2]

   print 'Input filea is:\t', inputfilea
   print 'Input fileb is:\t', inputfileb
   print 'Output file is:\t', outputfile
   f_out = open(outputfile, 'w');

  with open(inputfilea,"r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith(" "):            
                    partial_in= line.replace('cell', "")
                    partial_in= partial_in.replace(' ', "")
                    partial_in= partial_in.strip('\n')

                    with open(inputfileb,"r") as infileb:
                           for line in infileb:
                            if partial_in in line:

                                print line


   #call main

   if __name__ == "__main__":

     main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Sample of the  output ( see that it works for first input and not the second) :

```
   the input from the first file is DFF_0/Q_reg
   the corresponding line from the second file is 
    DFFSR \DFF_0/Q_reg  ( .D(G10), .CLK(CK), .R(R), .Q(G5) );

    the input from the first file is U1

    the corresponding line from the second file is 
     OR2X1 U12 ( .A(G0), .B(n4), .Y(n9) );

     the corresponding line from the second file is 
      AND2X1 U11 ( .A(n3), .B(n9), .Y(n6) );

     the corresponding line from the second file is 
     INVX1 U15 ( .A(G5), .Y(n13) );

     the corresponding line from the second file is 
     INVX1 U16 ( .A(n13), .Y(n14) );

     the corresponding line from the second file is 
     INVX1 U13 ( .A(G7), .Y(n11) );

    the corresponding line from the second file is 
    INVX1 U14 ( .A(n11), .Y(n12) );

    the corresponding line from the second file is 
     INVX1 U1 ( .A(G17), .Y(n1) );
```

Sample of the first input file ( the one that have the sorted elements):

```
       module s27
        cell U4
        cell U12
        cell U3
        cell U11
        cell U15
        cell U16
        cell U13
        cell U14
        cell U10
        cell U9
        cell U8
        cell U7
        cell U6
        cell DFF_0/Q_reg
        cell U1
        cell DFF_1/Q_reg
        cell U2
```

And finally sample of the second input file( the one I want to sort)

```
         INVX1 U4 ( .A(G6), .Y(n4) );
         OR2X1 U12 ( .A(G0), .B(n4), .Y(n9) );
         INVX1 U3 ( .A(G3), .Y(n3) );
         AND2X1 U11 ( .A(n3), .B(n9), .Y(n6) );
         INVX1 U15 ( .A(G5), .Y(n13) );
         INVX1 U16 ( .A(n13), .Y(n14) );
         INVX1 U13 ( .A(G7), .Y(n11) );
         INVX1 U14 ( .A(n11), .Y(n12) );
         OR2X1 U10 ( .A(G1), .B(n12), .Y(n5) );
         AND2X1 U9 ( .A(n5), .B(n9), .Y(n8) );
         OR2X1 U8 ( .A(n14), .B(n8), .Y(n7) );
         OR2X1 U7 ( .A(n6), .B(n7), .Y(G17) );
         AND2X1 U6 ( .A(G0), .B(G17), .Y(G10) );
         DFFSR \DFF_0/Q_reg  ( .D(G10), .CLK(CK), .R(R), .Q(G5) );
         INVX1 U1 ( .A(G17), .Y(n1) );
         DFFSR \DFF_1/Q_reg  ( .D(n1), .CLK(CK), .R(R), .Q(G6) );
         INVX1 U2 ( .A(G2), .Y(n2) );
         AND2X1 U5 ( .A(n5), .B(n2), .Y(G13) );
         DFFSR \DFF_2/Q_reg  ( .D(G13), .CLK(CK), .R(R), .Q(G7) );
```

Comment: You can use `==` instead of `in`. `"A1" in "A11" -> True"` `"A1" == "A11" -> False`.

Comment: Also it'd better if you include your sample input. It's hard to see -at least for me- what comes from where.

Comment: I just added the input files and I cant use == becasue I am looking for part of the line so the ordered cell is just the part that I want to sort the entire line based on it

Comment: Please fix the indentation, Python is very sensitive in that aspect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in comments, you can use `==`.
Looking at your sample inputs, your *words* are always at second word in your lines. So you can split the lines from both input files then check their elements at index-1.

```
with open(inputfilea,"r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if line.startswith(" "):
            partial_in = line.strip().split()[1] #splits the line and gets 2nd word
            with open(inputfileb,"r") as infileb:
                for line2 in infileb:
                    if line2: #check if it's not empty line
                    #last strip added because of DFF lines has backslashes infront of them
                        if partial_in == line2.strip().split()[1].strip("\\"):
                            print partial_in, line2,
                            #since you wanted to write to a file, instead of print
                            #f_out.write(line2)
```

Which outputs this:

```
U4          INVX1 U4 ( .A(G6), .Y(n4) );
U12          OR2X1 U12 ( .A(G0), .B(n4), .Y(n9) );
U3          INVX1 U3 ( .A(G3), .Y(n3) );
U11          AND2X1 U11 ( .A(n3), .B(n9), .Y(n6) );
U15          INVX1 U15 ( .A(G5), .Y(n13) );
U16          INVX1 U16 ( .A(n13), .Y(n14) );
U13          INVX1 U13 ( .A(G7), .Y(n11) );
U14          INVX1 U14 ( .A(n11), .Y(n12) );
U10          OR2X1 U10 ( .A(G1), .B(n12), .Y(n5) );
U9          AND2X1 U9 ( .A(n5), .B(n9), .Y(n8) );
U8          OR2X1 U8 ( .A(n14), .B(n8), .Y(n7) );
U7          OR2X1 U7 ( .A(n6), .B(n7), .Y(G17) );
U6          AND2X1 U6 ( .A(G0), .B(G17), .Y(G10) );
DFF_0/Q_reg          DFFSR \DFF_0/Q_reg  ( .D(G10), .CLK(CK), .R(R), .Q(G5) );
U1          INVX1 U1 ( .A(G17), .Y(n1) );
DFF_1/Q_reg          DFFSR \DFF_1/Q_reg  ( .D(n1), .CLK(CK), .R(R), .Q(G6) );
U2          INVX1 U2 ( .A(G2), .Y(n2) );
```

Comment: It worked for the first line, then it gave me this error :                       File "./netlist_ordering.py", line 39, in main
    if partial_in == lineb.strip().split()[1].strip("\\"):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ah sorry, corrected. That error occured because that line is empty. So needed to filter out empty lines with `if line2:`.

Comment: Welcome. :) BTW, looking at your question history, you haven't accepted an answer yet. If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Also, Thanks for telling me that, I am pretty novice in stack overflow